# old form keeps running with the old design even after the design of it has been changed

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB,I am working on a project and I have started with the design of my project,I design my main form of the project which I didn't like so I changedbthe design of the form but when I run the project the form with the old design keeps on popping up.

I deleted the exe of the project,I rebuilded the project but still nothing's seem to work.Please help me out with the problem.Thankyou

Comment: Reboot, then try "Clean Project" before rebuilding.

Comment: I would try a right click on the solution and select rebuild solution.

Comment: Try the `Clean` and `Rebuild` options from the `Build` menu.  If that doesn't work, close VS and then delete the `bin` and `obj` subfolders from the project folder.

Comment: Thanks alot...that helped.